# named groups splitting regardless of position of match

Tags: c#, regex

Having a hard time explaining what I mean, so here is what I want to do

I want any sentence to be parsed along the pattern of

```
text #something a few words [someothertext]
```

for this, the matching sentence would be

```
Jeremy is trying #20 times to [understand this]
```

And I would name 4 groups, as text, time, who, subtitle

However, I could also write

```
#20  Jeremy is trying [understand this] times to
```

and still get the tokens
    #20
    Jeremy is trying
    times to
    understand this

corresponding to the right groups

As long as the delimited tokens can separate the 2 text only tokens, I'm fine.

Is this even possible? I've tried a few regex's and failed miserably (am still experimenting but finding myself spending way too much time learning it)

Note: The order of the tokens can be random. If this isn't possible with regex then I guess I can live with a fixed order.

edit: fixed a typo. clarified further what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alternate on the different types of text. Using named groups means that one group would have a `Success` value equal to true for each match.

This pattern should do what you need:

```
@"(?<Number>#\d+\b)|(?<Subtitle>\[.+?])|\s*(?<Text>(?:.(?!#\d+\b|\[.*?]))+)\s*"
```

- `(?<Number>#\d+\b)` - matches `#` followed by one or more digits, up to a word boundary
- `(?<Subtitle>\[.+?])` - non-greedy matching of text between square brackets
- `\s*(?<Text>(?:.(?!#\d+\b|\[.*?]))+)\s*` - trims spaces at either end of the string, and the named capture group uses an approach that matches a single character at a time provided that the negative look-ahead fails to match if it detects text that would match the other 2 text patterns of interest (numbers and subtitles).

Example usage:

```
var inputs = new[] 
{ 
    "Jeremy is trying #20 times to [understand this]",
    "#20 Jeremy is trying [understand this] times to"
};
string pattern = @"(?<Number>#\d+\b)|(?<Subtitle>\[.+?])|\s*(?<Text>(?:.(?!#\d+\b|\[.*?]))+)\s*";
foreach (var input in inputs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input: " + input);
    foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
    {
        // skip first group, which is the entire matched text
        var group = m.Groups.Cast<Group>().Skip(1).First(g => g.Success);
        Console.WriteLine(group.Value);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Alternately, this example demonstrates how to pair the named groups to the matches:

```
var re = new Regex(pattern);
foreach (var input in inputs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input: " + input);
    var query = from Match m in re.Matches(input)
                from g in re.GetGroupNames().Skip(1)
                where m.Groups[g].Success
                select new
                {
                    GroupName = g,
                    Value = m.Groups[g].Value
                };
    foreach (var item in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", item.GroupName, item.Value);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: wow, impressive. At least to the slow brain of mine when it comes to regex. I found another posters solution which worked (with the accepted limitation that token position would be fixed), but this is even more flexible. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand this correctly, you're looking for four phrases:

1) 1+ words of normal text
2) 1 word of text prefixed by a #
3) 1+ words of normal text
4) 1+ words of text wrapped by [ ]

My (admittedly slow and regex-less) suggestion would be to find the indexes of the #, [, and ] characters, then use several calls to string.Substring().

This would be acceptable for relatively small strings and a relatively small number of iterations, although with much larger strings this would be extremely slow.

Comment: Yes, I could go the manual parse via index/substring, but wanted to see if there's a faster way to do it via Regex. Managed to find a fix but had to forego option of having any position for the tokens - but I can live with that